# Convert string of zeroes to Int (retaining zeroes)

Tags: haskell

I wish to convert something like "0000" to 0000.

When I use

```
read "0000" :: Int
```

The result is

```
0
```

Many thanks!

Comment: and what is 0000?

Comment: why do u want that?

Comment: @Redu 0000 is an Int

Comment: @Tanuj Yadav it is part of my planned solution to a CodeWars exercise

Comment: 0000 is not an Int!  If you want to preserve the size and values as number perhaps consider a list.  `map digitToInt "0000"`

Comment: @karakfa Ah, I see. I didn't know this, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `0000` of type `Int` which is different from `0`, so this isn't possible. This isn't specific to Haskell: you'll see the same in any other language with numeric types (i.e. basically any language at all).

But when you say "the result is `0`", you should more correctly say that result is *printed as* `0`, and generally you will have functions which allow you to print the same value as `0000`, but again won't distinguish between `0` and `0000` integer values.

If you want to preserve this information, you need a different type. Which one, depends on what exactly you need. E.g. it could be

```
data Digits = Digits [Int]
```

where each element of list is from `0` to `9` (or use `[Int]` directly). Or

```
data IntWithPaddingZeros = IntWithPaddingZeros { value :: Int, paddingZeros :: Int }
```

Etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a new data type like `MyInt` or say `Mint` and tell the compiler how to display it.

```
data Mint = M Int
instance Show Mint where
  show (M n) = "000" ++ show n

*Main> M 7
0007
```

This, of course, is a very simple example. You may come up with a more conceptual showing function which could deduce the number of zeroes to add if the integer is more than 1 digit.

OK let's develop our showing function a little further...

```
data Mint = M Int
instance Show Mint where
  show (M n) = replicate (3 - (round . (logBase 10) . fromIntegral) n ) '0' ++ show n

*Main> M 133
0133
*Main> M 22
0022
*Main> M 0
0000
*Main> M 1453
1453
```